# on focus not working in asp textbox

Tags: javascript, asp.net

On entering rate and quantity I want the total amount to be calculated automatically, so I tried the following.

```
function getAmt()
{   
    if(isNaN(document.getElementById('<%=TxtRate.ClientID%>').value))
    {
        alert("Illegal Rate Entered, Please Check It Out.");
        document.getElementById('<%=TxtRate.ClientID%>').focus;

        return;
    }
    else if(isNaN(document.getElementById('<%=TxtQty.ClientID%>').value))
    {
        alert("Illegal Quantity Entered, Please Check It Out.");
        document.getElementById('<%=TxtQty.ClientID%>').focus;

        return;
    }   
    document.getElementById('<%=TxtAmt.ClientID%>').value=parseFloat
        (document.getElementById('<%=TxtRate.ClientID%>').value)*parseFloat
        (document.getElementById('<%=TxtQty.ClientID%>').value)
}
```

Now I created a text box:

```
<TextBox ID="TxtAmt" runat="server" BorderStyle="Solid" onFocus="getAmt()">
```

This code is not running.. what am i missing ??

Comment: Your code works fine for me if I key in a value in the TxtRate box & the TxtQty box and then click on in to the txtAmt box.

Are you wanting the amount to update when you change the values in TxtRate or TxtQty?

Comment: What is not working ? Do you get an error ? `focus` is a function, you should put parenthesis `focus()`

Comment: focus() is not my problem. My problem is that the amount is not coming automatically in the TxtAmt box and yes I do want to update the amount whenever the rate or quantity or both are changed..

Comment: My code worked perfectly in IE8 but not working in IE9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it out

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "foc", "document.getElementById('" + TxtAmt.ClientID + "').focus();", true);
```

Use above code segment when you want to focus the txt amt and once the txtamt is focus your function will calculate the amount value based on the provided rate and quantity..

If you find it useful, please mark it as your answer else let me know...

Comment: The rate textbox, qty textbox and amount textbox are placed below each other and tab index set as 1,2,3. So on pressing TAB button from rate to amount, the amount textbox will naturally get focus after qty.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var amtText = $('#' + '<%=TxtAmt.ClientID%>');
amtText.bind('focus', getAmt()); // using jQuery here
```

If you don't want use jQuery (or any other JavaScript library), then you have to user pure JavaScript. However to attach a handler (an event listener) to an event in the browser, you have 2 ways:

1. You can use the *onevent* attribute of the HTML element (like *onclick*, or *onfocus*, etc.), which is commonly known as DOM Events Level 1
2. Or you can use `addEventListener` and `removeEventListeners` of [DOM Level 2 Events](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/), or `attachEvent` and `detachEvent` in IE8- browsers. For more information and samples about it, see this [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener) page.

Comment: I am not familiar with jquery. can i write this in <script> tag ??

Comment: @Dev, too bad you're not familiar with jQuery. I suggest you start learning it right now, :), because, it's worthy. However, I updated the answer.

Comment: @Dev, StackOverflow and StackExchange websites generally work on voting mechanism. If this question helped you in any way, vote it up, so that you help (just like others) filter content based on their value. :)